# Azure ML Batch Endpoint Dynamically change datastore output

Tags: endpoint, azure-machine-learning-service

In Azure Machine Learning:

I wish to create a Batch Endpoint that takes as input the name of a (registered) , read and process every file under folder  and output each resulting file (1:1) to the datastore's  folder. Each datastore relates to an azure blob storage's container. (The containers have to be separate for privacy purposes.)

The default behaviour of batch endpoint returning a single file that aggregates the mini-batches is not desired as the aggregated result would be too large to meaningfully process. I simply wish the batch to handle each file individually and write them to a desired datastore.

I have checked numerous Azure docs but I find myself running into obscure errors such as
`azureml.dataprep.api.mltable._mltable_helper.UserErrorException: Invalid mode wb, supported modes are ['r', 'rb'], both means read as byte array`

I followed the example of custom-outputs-parquet/custom-output-batch-blob.ipynb:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-deploy-model-custom-output?view=azureml-api-2&tabs=cli

But I wish to dynamically change the (input and) destination datastore of the batch job itself.

- All datastores are registered (connected with an azure blob storage)
- I succesfully changed the input uri to a datastore.
- Using azure-storage-blob within python was also succesful, but this would keep outputting to the default datastore. As there are many files, this would blow up disk usage.

```
%%writefile code/batch_drive.py

import os
import pickle
import glob
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path
from typing import List

def init():
    global model
    global output_path

    output_path = os.environ["AZUREML_BI_OUTPUT_PATH"]
    # What change to output_path to make?
    # Or...

    model_path = os.environ["AZUREML_MODEL_DIR"]
    model_file = glob.glob(f"{model_path}/*/*.pkl")[-1]

    with open(model_file, "rb") as file:
        model = pickle.load(file)


def run(mini_batch: List[str]):
    # Should I make a change here?

    for file_path in mini_batch:
        data = pd.read_csv(file_path)
        pred = model.predict(data)
        data["prediction"] = pred
        output_file_name = Path(file_path).stem
        output_file_path = os.path.join(output_path, output_file_name + "result.csv")
        
        data.to_csv(output_file_path)

    return mini_batch
```

It is not clear to me where `os.environ["AZUREML_BI_OUTPUT_PATH"]` is instantiated or how it can be dynamically changed (without running into 'invalid mode wb').

With each invoke hopefully being:

```
input= Input(type=AssetTypes.URI_FOLDER, path=f"azureml://subscriptions/{subscription_id}/resourcegroups/{resource_group}/workspaces/{workspace}/datastores/{datastore}/paths/input")

output = Output(type=AssetTypes.URI_FOLDER, path=f"azureml://subscriptions/{subscription_id}/resourcegroups/{resource_group}/workspaces/{workspace}/datastores/{datastore}/paths/output")

job = ml_client.batch_endpoints.invoke(
    endpoint_name=endpoint.name, deployment_name=deployment.name, inputs={'datastore': input}, outputs={'destout': output}
)
```

For a pipeline (job) itself the the desired datastore can be adjusted dynamically when using a notebook, but I wish to achieve the same with a batch endpoint when invoking different datastores' uris.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the scenario, to avoid storing the results in the default datastore. You can specify the output datastore with:

```py
ds2 = ml_client.datastores.get("test")
data_path = "batch-jobs/my-unique-path"
output = Output(type=AssetTypes.URI_FILE, path=f"{ds2.id}/paths/{data_path}")
```

[image]

Invoking the endpoint with updated output path will store the results successfully.
[image]

Comment: I got this far as well, but how can I do this dynamically?
That is: I invoke the batch with <container name>, and it will get data from <container>/input, and writes to <container>/output.

The issue I have is that it seems for the pipeline/job I have to predefine input and output and cannot dynamically change the destination (without hacking it together using azure blob storage client...)